# What does פ׳ ב׳ פ׳ stand for in the context of prayer (specifically related to prayer #8 of the Amidah)?

Tags: hebrew, names, shemoneh-esrei, prayer-book, acronyms

In the Siddur I am using (*Siddurenu*, The Prayer Book Press, 1961), there is a supplemental prayer directly below prayer #8 of the Amida (on page 56) that prays for healing of specific individuals. (It starts with ויהי רצון מלפניך.) In that prayer, the abbreviation or shorthand פ׳ ב׳ פ׳ appears. In the English translation of that prayer, an ellipsis ("...") appears in the same place, and it is clear that we are meant to fill in the specific names of the people we are praying for in that space. So I think I understand the practical meaning of the פ׳ ב׳ פ׳ in the Hebrew version of the prayer, but I'm just wondering what specific words these letters stand for that imply that we should fill in the names of the people we are praying for there.

As a side note, I'm also wondering if there's a specific way we should say the names of of the people we are praying for. I know that when called up for Torah readings people's names are generally said as [Hebrew name] ben/bat [father's Hebrew name]. Should names be said in that way here too when reading in Hebrew this supplemental prayer asking for the healing of specific individuals?

Any help answering these questions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 8th blessing, which is focused on healing the sick, there is a supplemental prayer as you point out, that a person can add in if they know anyone in particular who is unwell.

The "פ׳ ב׳ פ׳" stands for פלוני בן פלונית. or if a female (thanks @DoubleAA) פלונית בת פלונית. The term פלוני\פלונית is the equivalent of saying a generic name like Joe Bloggs the son of... which is indicating for you to add in there the name of the person who is unwell.

As far as your side note, yes, the names are ideally said in Hebrew along with the name of the mother,  E.g. Yitzchak (the full hebrew name of the person who is unwell) ben ("the son of" - substitute with bat/bas if they are the daughter of someone) Sarah (the name of the mother).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! Definitely answers the question I had.

Comment: Pleasure happy to help :-)